# How to use onTouchEvent?

Tags: android, touch-event

what's wrong with this code.When I swype the screen from up to down I want the text "Down" to be written and else the other side.But on Emulator nothing changes.What's the problem?

```
    public class Draw extends View{ 
int ratioX = 50;
int ratioY = 350;
float dx = 0;
float dy = 0;
int newX;
int newY;
String dir="Hello";

public Draw(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public  boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    float touchX = 0;
    float touchY = 0;
    switch(event.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        touchX = event.getX();
        touchY = event.getY();
        return true;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        dx = touchX - event.getX();
        dy = touchY - event.getY();
        if(Math.abs(dy) > Math.abs(dx)){
            if(dy > 0){
                dir = "DOWN";                
            }
            else{                   
                dir = "UP";                 
            }
        }
        else{
            if(dx > 0){
                dir = "RIGHT";
            }
            else{
                dir = "LEFT";
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
public void onDraw(Canvas c){   
    //Rect myRect = new Rect();
    //myRect.set(ratioX,c.getHeight()/8,ratioY,c.getWidth()/8);     
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    c.drawPaint(p);     
    //p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    //c.drawRect(myRect, p);
    p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    p.setTextSize(18);
    c.drawText(dir, 200, 360, p);
}
```

}

Nothing happens when I swype the screen! or should I use another method?

Comment: Will onTouch fire onDraw? First check what is the value of dir and then check whether onDraw is fired or not after the swipe.

Comment: yes, you should use GestureDetector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `invalidate()` your view when you want to change it's contents. The snippet below should help out;

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Other parts of method omitted for brevity
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            dx = touchX - event.getX();
            dy = touchY - event.getY();
            String newDir = dir;
            if(Math.abs(dy) > Math.abs(dx)){
                if(dy > 0){
                    newDir = "DOWN";                
                }
                else{                   
                    newDir = "UP";                 
                }
            }
            else{
                if(dx > 0){
                    newDir = "RIGHT";
                }
                else{
                    newDir = "LEFT";
                }
            }

            if (newDir != dir) {
                dir = newDir;
                // We only want to invalidate the view when your 'dir' value has changed.
                // onDraw() will then be triggered.
                invalidate();
            }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: both of your answer helped me.But I don't have enough rating to vote for them))) Anyway Thanks)

Answer (score 0):

Every time your `onTouchEvent` is called, the local floats `touchX` and `touchY` will be initialized to zero.  This has consequences in your logic that handles `ACTION_UP`:

```
dx = touchX - event.getX();
dy = touchY - event.getY();

if(Math.abs(dy) > Math.abs(dx)){
    if(dy > 0){
        dir = "DOWN";                
    } else {                   
        dir = "UP";                 
    }
}
```

`dx` and `dy` end up being -x and -y respectively.  After the `Math.abs()` calls, you're essentially testing if their finger is farther down the screen than it is across the screen.

Store the initial down coordinates as member variables and set them during `ACTION_DOWN`.

Comment: You declared two floats (touchX and touchY) inside the onTouchEvent method.  Do you see why every new call to onTouchEvent remakes them each time, and initializes them to zero?  Instead, declare them as  variables up at the top of your class definition.